# mysql query how to get the number of items within a week

Tags: mysql

I have a database that store transaction logs, I would like to count all of the logs for this current week only. Date is stored in Unix

Get the current week starting from Monday to today.

```
$week = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n'), date('j'), date('Y')) - ((date('N')-1)*3600*24);
```

MySQL query

```
$q = 'SELECT count( distinct ID) as count FROM STATUS WHERE PERSON ='.$db->qstr($id).' AND DATE
(FROM_UNIXTIME(STATUS_DATE)) ='.$db->qstr($week);
```

can anyone advise me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: First thing I see is WHERE PERSON ='.$db->qstr($id).' doesn't have quotes around it...if PERSON is a varchar column this will be required.

Comment: What data type is WORK_ORDER_STATUS_DATE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
WHERE DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())>=DAYOFWEEK(WORK_ORDER_STATUS_DATE)
```

or you could use:

```
WHERE WEEK(CURDATE())=WEEK(WORK_ORDER_STATUS_DATE)
```

Comment: WEEK worked great. I was reading php manual. I see month, year and date but was not sure I could have used WEEK as well. thanks chad.